# question on holomorphicity

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in an open set $\Omega$. Prove that in any one of the
following cases:

(a) $Re(f)$ is constant;

(b) $Im(f)$ is constant;

(c) $|f|$ is constant;

one can conclude that f is constant.
it is given as an exercise how can i do it polease someone give me a hint.

Comment: "Holomorphicity" does not exist. The word is "holomorphy".

Comment: $\Omega$ should be connected. ("Holomorphicity" is also a word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mrf has pointed out, you need connectedness. If $\Omega$ is not connected, then the function $f$ equal to $1$ on one connected component of $\Omega$ and to $1+i$ on the remaining part of $\Omega$ satisfies (a) but is not constant.

To prove (c), you can proceed as follows. If $\vert f\vert$ is constant, you may of course assume that the constant $c$ is $\neq 0$. Since $\vert f\vert^2=f\bar f$ is constant you have $\frac{\partial (f\bar f)}{\partial z}=0$. Now, $$\frac{\partial (f\bar f)}{\partial z}=f\,\frac{\partial\bar f}{\partial z}+\bar f\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\bar f\, f'$$
because $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}=0$ (Cauchy-Riemann) and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=f'$; so we get $\bar f\times f'=0$. Multiplying by $f$, this gives $c^2 f'=0$; so $f'=0$ and $f$ is constant by connectedness.

To prove (a), apply (c) to $g=e^{f}$ (so that $\vert g\vert=e^{{\rm Re}(f)}$). This gives $g'=0$, i.e. $f'e^f=0$, and hence $f'=0$ since $e^f$ is nowhere $0$.

To prove (b), apply (a) to $if$.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I just noticed, from the other users's answers, that you didn't say connected. Of course, we need connected :)

Hint:

In the three cases you have that $f(\Omega)$ is a subset of

a) a line

b) a line

c) a circle.

Consider the open mapping theorem.

Comment: +1, but it's probably simpler to do it directly from the Cauchy-Riemann equestion.

Comment: @T.Bongers True, but since the OP didn't provide any background, I took some artistic license :)

Comment: The artist's performance is perfect:+1

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not true as stated. You need to assume that $\Omega$ is connected as well.

Assuming you don't know the open mapping theorem, split $f$ into its real and imaginary parts: $f = u+iv$ and use Cauchy-Riemann's equations.

For a), you have that $u$ is constant, so $u'_x = u'_y = 0$. Cauchy-Riemann implies that $v'_x = v'_y = 0$, so $v$ is constant (here you are using that $\Omega$ is connected).

b) is very similar to a)

For c) it's probably easier to start from the fact that $|f|^2 = u^2 + v^2$ is constant. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: @Georg it means that$\f(\omega)$ is not open in all the cases